# Texture data not being passed to sampler in fragment shader

Tags: opengl

I need to pass a 2D (Rectangle) texture to my fragment shader. The data in the texture must be read in the sampler as a uniform. Depending on the value read in the texture, the color of a pixel will or will not be changed.

here is my code in the API to bind texture and sampler:

```
//create texture and sampler
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
GLuint CosineTexture;
glGenTextures(1,&CosineTexture);
glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE,1,GL_RGBA,1440,1080);

glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE,0,0,0,1440,1080,GL_RGBA,GL_FLOAT,dataCosines1);

GLuint SensorCosines;
glGenSamplers(1,&SensorCosines);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE,CosineTexture);
glBindSampler(0,SensorCosines);
```

and here is my code in the shader to receive and read from the texture:

```
uniform samplerRect SensorCosines;
...

float textureValue;
textureValue = texture(SensorCosines, Bin).r;
```

Nothing happens. So, I guess that my texture is not being passed to the shader. My feeling is that it is at the level of binding texture to sampler in the API but I have no clue what is my error.

Comment: I for got to show some details in the shader. So here it is: uniform samplerRect SensorCosines; ....  vec2 Bin; ... Bin[0] = float(XCosines)+0.5;
 Bin[1] = float(YCosines)+0.5;   Sorry. Robert

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE,1,GL_RGBA,1440,1080);
> ```

This call will produce an OpenGL error. Specifically, `GL_INVALID_ENUM`. You *must* use [sized image formats](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format) when using `glTexStorage` functions. `GL_RGBA` is not a sized image format.

You may have other problems in un-shown code, but this is certainly one of the issues.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will look for that.

Comment: I have made change in the code and used TEXTURE_2D instead with a 1024 X 1024 size texture. There is still no data passed to the sampler2D. I querry OpenGL for errors and the function gluErrorString(err) always returns "no error". Do you think my problem could be related to the way I create the texture data? Here it is:float ***dataCosines;

   // Allocate memory
   dataCosines = new GLfloat**[1024];
   for (int i = 0; i < 1024; ++i) {
  dataCosines[i] = new GLfloat*[1024];
  for (int j = 0; j < 1024; ++j)
    dataCosines[i][j] = new GLfloat[4];
   }

Comment: @RobertB: Things like that are why you should provide a [MCVE] if you expect to get a good answer.

Comment: As you can see, I am a newcomer both to OpenGL and to StackOverFlow. I wish to thank you for your kind help. I will try to put something better together, respecting the StackOverFlow format.

Comment: you were right. The function gluErrorString(err) always returned no error but the function glGetError() returned the error code for GL_INVALID_ENUM as you expected.  I actually needed to write GL_RGBA16 instead of GL_RGBA in glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,1,GL_RGBA,1024,1024); The case is now solved. Thanks.